# How to make equation text size to be normal

Tags: equations, text-manipulation

The letters in my equation are shrinking and I'm trying to revert that:

[image: my attempt]

I'd like them to appear as follows:

[image: from the book]

If you notice you can see that the parenthesis' size on second image vary like 3 times while on the first equation it doesn't change much. In the first image the fraction W over h are shrinking down how do I make them not to shrink?

```
\begin{equation}
\Delta L = 0.412 \cdot h \frac{(\epsilon_{ref} + 0.3)\left( \frac{W}{h} + 0.264 \right)}
{(\epsilon_{ref} - 0.258)\left( \frac{W}{h} + 0.8 \right)} \label{for:fringes}
\end{equation}
```

I'd like to know how to change the equation's font to mach the on in the second image.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command,

```
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\Delta L}{h} = 0.412 \dfrac{(\epsilon_{ref} + 0.3)\left( \dfrac{W}{h} + 0.264 \right)}
{(\epsilon_{ref} - 0.258)\left( \dfrac{W}{h} + 0.8 \right)} \label{for:fringes}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use package `amsmath` (`mathtools`), `\dfrac` and `\text`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Delta L = 0.412 \cdot h \dfrac{(\epsilon_\text{ref} + 0.3)
         \left( \dfrac{W}{h} + 0.264 \right)}
         {(\epsilon_\text{ref} - 0.258)
        \left( \dfrac{W}{h} + 0.8 \right)}\label{for:fringes} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: although not strictly necessary, it would probably be a good idea to put braces around the entire `{\text{ref}}` subscript.